# ubuntu mysql php and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, apache2

```
apache2 -version
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2021-06-18T11:06:22
```

```
mysqld --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${version}\n' phpmyadmin
4:5.1.1+dfsg1-3+bionic1
```

```
php -b
PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 30 2021 13:03:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin is working fine, login page appear and i can login. But i cant use phpmyadmin to administrate my database i become a 500 error in a red box. What is wrong? All Packages are installed with apt.

Comment: Have you installed `php8.0-mysql`?

Comment: yes, look at my answer ist a problem with symfony.

Answer (score 9):

After i enable the error reporting from php with:

```
/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 6143
```

And restart apache with

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

become following error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unknown named parameter $$response in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1140 Stack trace: #0

looks like https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/8e34978e4e2c4bf7dac97e44e904368c4cfb54f8

i fixed this with

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/newInstanceArgs($arguments)/newInstanceArgs(array_values($arguments))/g' /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php && cat /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php | grep "newInstanceArgs"
```

Comment: Thank you. Your "fix" works :-)